# GAE Channel ID for non-logged in user

Tags: google-app-engine

I've got a GAE in Python and I am using the Channel API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/functions

All the examples I can find use a logged in user's id for the client id. What if the user is not logged in? What can be used for as a reliable id in this case? Should I create a cookie or session with Python and store an arbitrary id in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anything at all for the clientid, the samples just happen to use the logged-in user's id. Whatever your app uses to associate a client with their data, you can use.